# Inconsistent Results - Jupyter Numpy & Transpose

Tags: arrays, numpy, jupyter, transpose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvG87.png)

I am getting odd behavior with Jupyter/Numpy/Tranpose()/1D Arrays.

I found another post where transpose() will **not** transpose a 1D array, but in previous Jupyter notebooks, it does.

I have an example where it is inconsistent, and I do not understand:

Please see the picture attached of my jupyter notebook if 2 more or less identical arrays with 2 different outputs.

It seems it IS and IS NOT transposing the 1D array. Inconsistency is bad

outputs is (1000,) and (1,1000), why does this occur?

```
# GENERATE WAVEORM:
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
N   = 1000
fxc = []
fxn = []
for t in range(0,N):
    fxc.append(A1*m.sin(2.0*pi*50.0*dt*t) + A2*m.sin(2.0*pi*120.0*dt*t))
    fxn.append(A1*m.sin(2.0*pi*50.0*dt*t) + A2*m.sin(2.0*pi*120.0*dt*t) + 5*np.random.normal(u,std,size=1))
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# TAKE TRANSPOSE:
#---------------------------------
fc = np.transpose(np.array(fxc))
fn = np.transpose(np.array(fxn))
#---------------------------------


# PRINT DIMENSION:
#---------------------------------
print(fc.shape)
print(fn.shape)
#---------------------------------
```

Comment: What is your question here? Please, write a title that summarizes the specific problem with a question.

Comment: look at the shape of `np.array(fxc)` and fxn, first.  Are they 1d or 2d?

Comment: Look at the picture, as I say to.

Comment: @Master-P, the picture doesn't show `np.array(fxc).shape` and `np.array(fxn).shape`.  If you looked at those, you would have found that the shape discrepancy occurs before you've called `np.transpose` (i.e. this is not really a problem with numpy's transpose operation).

Comment: yeah I just plotted it and assumed. Sorry everyone, also given the only difference WAS the random noise, I should have also clued in on that. This is my first post, new to python, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `size=1` from your call to `numpy.random.normal`.  Then it will return a *scalar* instead of a 1-d array of length 1.

For example,

```
In [2]: np.random.normal(0, 3, size=1)
Out[2]: array([0.47058288])

In [3]: np.random.normal(0, 3)
Out[3]: 4.350733438283539
```

Using `size=1` in your code is a problem, because it results in `fxn` being a list of 1-d arrays (e.g. something like `[[0.123], [-.4123], [0.9455], ...]`.  When NumPy converts that to an array, it has shape `(N, 1)`.  Transposing such an array results in the shape `(1, N)`.

`fxc`, on the other hand, is a list of scalars (e.g. something like `[0.123,  0.456, ...]`).  When converted to a NumPy array, it will be a 1-d array with shape `(N,)`.  NumPy's transpose operation swaps dimensions, but it does not create new dimensions, so transposing a 1-d array does nothing.

Comment: Damn it! haha I totally missed that.. that worked! thanks a bunch for your fast response Warren!